# An alternative to Vodka to pair with caviar

Tags: recommendations, pairing, vodka

With some Russian friends coming I intend upon serving caviar in the correct manner.  Here is a link to [The Telegraph's](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/foodanddrink/recipes/4570382/Caviar-with-blini-and-the-works.html) idea of what I should be doing as far as the caviar is concerned.  However I know that my friends do not like Vodka!  What other alcoholic drink can I serve, yet keep the Russian feel?

Here's the caviar - now what to drink?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your main criterion, especially if you are serving sturgeon caviar, should be something to freshen the palate without leaving a strong aftertaste.

A brut champagne goes exceptionally well. If keeping the Russian theme is important and you have a good eastern European shop at hand, you could try to get a Russian or Ukrainian Шампанское. Be aware that many Russian and Ukrainian wines tend to be much sweeter than a western European would expect; make sure it is Брют / Brut, and ideally try a bottle before serving it.

Comment: Good point about the freshen the palate.  I will search on-line for the right Шампанское (champagne), and then possibly have to buy it on-line as well.

Answer (score 3):

Caviar has a delicate flavor, and it shouldn’t compete with another ingredient, which could overwhelm it which would include either food or drink.

Being a non fan of either vodka or champagne, I would like to recommend a dry white wine, which by the way should always be chilled. I would be inclined to suggest a  Sauvignon Blanc as an example.

> Sauvignon Blanc
>
> This is one of the driest, crispest wines. This lean, clean wine is often herbaceous with well balanced acidity and underlying fruits. You can find Sauvignon Blanc grown around the world. Major growing regions include Bordeaux, New Zealand, the Loire Valley, South Africa, Austria, California, and Washington State. [Types of Dry White Wine](http://wine.lovetoknow.com/wiki/Types_of_Dry_White_Wine)

There are some traditional drinks that are generally paired with caviar asthe following can demonstrate.

> **What to Drink With Caviar**
>
> The most traditional drinks to pair it with:
>
> •Champagne (chilled) - any good champagne will usually do, but the absolute best is a fine traditional brut or extra-brut
>
> •Vodka (chilled)
>
> •Dry white wine (chilled)
>
> And the non-so-traditional ones:
>
> •Beer (need you ask? Ice-cold!)The tailgating party just got a first-class upgrade! The trick is to go for light beers (domestic or imported, your choice). **Beers that are too dark will overwhelm the palate, and take away from the crisp and smooth flavor of the caviar.** To best enjoy, keep it simple, and pair a tall glass of ice-cold beer with a scoopful of caviar. - [Caviar Pairings](https://www.gourmetfoodstore.com/caviar-pairings-15146)